# Yocto build error: Building image with debian package management

Tags: yocto

I've build images with the default RPM package management, but now that I want to build an image with debian package management instead of RPM, Yocto returns an error in the last steps of `image do_rootfs` step.

The error;

```
update-alternatives: Error: not linking /home/yoctouser/build/tmp/work/myimage/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/bin/dpkg-deb to /bin/busybox.nosuid since /home/yoctouser/build/tmp/work/jetson_nano-poky-linux/myimage/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/bin/dpkg-deb exists and is not a link

ERROR: myimage-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Postinstall scriptlets of ['busybox'] have failed. If the intention is to defer them to first boot,
then please place them into pkg_postinst_ontarget_${PN} ().
Deferring to first boot via 'exit 1' is no longer supported.
Details of the failure are in /home/yoctouser/build/tmp/work/jetson_nano-poky-linux/myimage/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.
ERROR: myimage-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: 
ERROR: myimage-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/yoctouser/build/tmp/work/jetson_nano-poky-linux/myimage/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.9391
ERROR: Task (/home/yoctouser/layers/meta-mylayer/images/myimage.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

There seems to be a problem building debian package management and busybox together.

**image.bb:**

```
DESCRIPTION = "Test image."

inherit core-image

inherit distro_features_check

IMAGE_FEATURES += "package-management"

IMAGE_LINGUAS ?= " "

IMAGE_INSTALL += " \
    ifupdown \
    dropbear \
"

export IMAGE_BASENAME = "myimage"
```

Building an `image-core-minimal` is without error. 
Deleting `tmp`folder has no change.

----------EDIT:-----------
More information about the layers used:

**bblayers.bb:**

```
  /home/yoctouser/layers/poky-zeus/meta \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/poky-zeus/meta-poky \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/poky-zeus/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/meta-tegra \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/meta-linaro/meta-linaro-toolchain \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-virtualization \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-selinux \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-security \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-iot-cloud \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-perl \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  /home/yoctouser/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
```

Using Zeus branch for all the layers, and master branch for meta-linaro as there is no zeus branch yet at the time of this writing. The master branch for meta-linaro does state compatability with the yocto/poky zeus branch in the `layer.conf` and there has been no problems with it so far.

Comment: Please add version information of your layers

Comment: As this post apparently is getting negative score, I assume it is because of lack of information and clarity. So I've attempted to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that one of the layers i was using, `meta-linaro`, has a `.bbappend` to `busybox` that configures `dpkg-deb` to be linked to busybox. I created a patch for the `meta-linaro` layer that removes that configuration and voilà, the build completes successfully.